# D365FO: Update non-editable table field with data entity

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I have a following problem: I have a `tableA` (standard FO table) that has a `fieldA` (string) with the `Allow Edit` property set to to **No**. Now the user would like to have several fieldA values changed with an added suffix, for example: FOO -> FOO_bar.

Can I do some sort of an CSV import that has old and new values or what would be the best way for start solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can by code update the field irrespective of the fields `AllowEdit` property. This only affects its use in forms.

You can import a file as described [here](https://d365gamer.blogspot.com/2018/08/x-code-to-import-data-from-csv-file-to.html).

```
public  void UploadFileData()
{    
    var fileUpload = File::GetFileFromUser() as FileUploadTemporaryStorageResult;
    var file = AsciiStreamIo::constructForRead(fileUpload.openResult());
    if (!file || file.status())
    {
        throw error("@SYS52680");
    }
    file.inFieldDelimiter(',');
    file.inRecordDelimiter('\r\n');
    for (var record = file.read(); !file.status(); record = file.read()) 
    {
        record = file.read();
        if (record)
        {
            info(strFmt("%1 - %2",conPeek(record,1),conPeek(record,2)));
        }
    }
}
```